# Remove dot´s from date

Tags: vb.net

I made a program that generates a daily index code.
It gets created from

- Employer (everyone has a number from 0-9)
- Date of serial code requested

Everything is working fine, but I wannt to remove the dots from the date
I tried things like

```
date.Text = date.Text.Replace(".""", """")
```

or

```
Dim clean as String
clean = myString.Replace(".", "")
```

But nothing happens

May be I just didnt unterstand the using... If yes, so please help me to find a alternative.
Ok i will try to explain better.
As I lunch it a textbox gets the date of today, the textbox is called date
Ive got a combobox, from there you select the employer. Every employer has a number. For example Andreas is Number 1.
I wannt to do something like:

```
if combobox1.text = "Andreas" then
dailyCode.text = "1" & date.text
end if
```

My problem is that the date is written with dots, the daily code should not have dots.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: pls post the code where the code is created and also how date is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your questions Details are still incomplete.still assuming that the `date`(still i am confused how are you using reserved keyword) is declared as date type itself,consider formatting it with  [Format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) itself.

Try using

```
Dim s As String = Format(date, "ddMMMyyyy")
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I tried but I get an error
Maybe I should change 
´Dim s As String = Format(date.now, "ddMMMyyyy")`

Comment: Ok I got it
@akhil kumar
I had to change date to date now and "ddMMMyyyy" to "ddMMyy"
You solved my problem :)

Comment: It was waiting for an argument " Of "

Comment: thats what i have been thinking of,how could you use reserved keyword `date`,i had an assumption you may have mistaken it with `date.now`.anyway you are wlecome.